# error in tfs2010 dashboard

Tags: sharepoint-2007, team-foundation-server

I have installed MOSS2007 along with TFS2010. While browsing through dashboards I found following error-

Excel Web Access-An error has occurred.

Please contact your system administrator if this problem persists.

The eventviewr is flooded with error-

Excel Services: Unexpected exception while trying to access Shared Services Database;. Error = Cannot open database "SharedServices1_DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Domain\Servername-01$'..

I have installed MOSS2007 on apptier of TFS Setup.

Please suggest.

Thanks Upfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link [Additional Dashboard in TFS2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/159488/additional-dashboard-in-tfs2010) we could enable the dashboard, but we faced another error as mentioned above.

Finally we found the solution as -

We added account 'Domain\Servername-01$ to SharedServices1_DB as-

SQL Server Management Studio > Logins > right click 'Domain\Servername-01$ > Properties > User Mapping >Check Map for SharedServices1_DB > For default schema select dbo > click ok

Note: We are using SQL Server 2008 and I have Administrator privilege on server as well as I have domian admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the "How to: Configure Settings for Dashboard Compatibility" detailed in the TFS2010 setup guide - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f

It would seem as though you haven't configured SSO and the Trusted Excel components.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for Reply...

We noticed that we have not given required permission to the account using which we configured SSO and Trusted Excel components. We have done that and then configured SSO and Trusted Excel. 

Still getting the same error and same eventvwr entries.